# How to search for users in firebase database?

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, uisearchbar

I have a search bar I want to display all firebase users and when the user starts typing. I want the search bar to display the picture and the the full name of the users (like Instagram).

```
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        searchBar()        
    }

         func searchBar (){
                navigationItem.searchController = searchController
                navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false

                searchController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                definesPresentationContext = true
            }
```